# Can anybody think of any good names for a PHP framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, names

I''m bulding my own PHP framework and I would appreciate some ideas for names as I'm stuck.
It's going to be a small, light MVC framework that helps you make sites. It doesn't have any of that scaffolding stuff or any other of the goodies that CakePHP provides, but it does have some clever database techniques. Anybody got any ideas for names? Thanks...

Comment: PHP Framework No. 299283

Answer (score 2):

CookiePHP - lighter than cake. :)

Comment: I actually like that a lot! :D

Comment: Sweet! I love that. Thanks, Eml!